# How to prove this Bessel's identity?

Tags: analysis

I've got a problem with proving this Bessel's identity:
$ J_0(t)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{J_{2n}(t)} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\varphi = \pi$ in the fundamental identity :

$$e^{i z \sin \varphi }=J_0(z)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}J_{2k}\cos{2k \varphi}+2i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}J_{2k-1}\sin{(2k+1) \varphi}$$

(Gradshteyn and Ryzhic, Academic Press, 1980 formulass 8.511 p. 973)